# How to watch a process sub-tree?

Tags: windows, process, operating-system, posix, watch

I am working on a code coverage tool. The monitored programs may spawn subprocesses that should also be covered. The process tree may be complex and involve non-covered processes. Using code coverage should not force the developer to modify the covered tool (he may not have control over all of it). I have a current solution to handle spawned processes: it patches the environment and tries to intercept spawned processes to cover. This is good-enough but is a workaround around the deeper issue: I need to watch a process subtree.

I am looking for a reliable solution to watch/monitor a process sub-tree: detect the creation and destruction of sub-processes in the sub-tree (including daemons/detached processes).

I expect to build something similar to file watchers, but for processes. My target platforms are Linux, Mac and Windows. I can write native code using system calls if needed. The covered code is in Javascript (Node.js) but such a process-watcher is not available in Node. The solution can use system-specific APIs.

This is a new problem area to me and I am not very familiar with the tools available in this domain. First of all, I would like to know if such a watcher is even possible given the existing system APIs. If it is possible, would it be possible to have rough pointers to relevant APIs?

My main system uses Linux, I know that process spawning is implemented with system calls, and that I can look into `/proc` to get information about the running processes. For Linux, my two current solutions are:

1. File watcher on `/proc`, but I am not sure how reliable it would be especially if the processes are short-lived (this also excludes polling).
2. Kernel module to intercept system calls? This is too heavy-handed and intrusive for a code-coverage tool. The current solution is good-enough but bringing it to "reliable" should be possible without perturbing the system too much.

Thanks in advance for any help

Comment: For Windows see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/process-explorer

Comment: @xmojmr Thanks for the link. It seems to be a GUI tool, not an API providing event emitters. Source code may be interesting but I cannot find it. In my "watch" has the programming meaning "subscribe to events" (not the "watch with your eyes" meaning ;D)

Comment: Process Explorer alternative with source code: https://processhacker.sourceforge.io/